# I want to count lines in a text file using console Application

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    int numOfLines1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\IMP\food.txt").Length;
    Console.WriteLine(numOfLines1.ToString());

    int numofLines2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\IMP\d.txt").Length;
    Console.WriteLine(numofLines2.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Which is giving me output like 5 1. but I want to get the output as like below:

> Food.txt is 5
>
> d.txt is 1.

How can it be possible to change the code? Please help.

Comment: change the content of the Console.WriteLine statements.

Comment: can you please show me the code . how to change ?

Comment: Look at this [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/586y06yf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
//your code
Console.WriteLine("Food.txt is {0}", numOfLines1);

//your code
Console.WriteLine("d.txt is {0}", numofLines2);

//your code
```

**EDIT:** Its a kind of hard coding but may solves your problem (To get the last file name):

```
var fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(your folder);

int number = 0;

string currentFile = string.Empty;

foreach (var item in fileNames)
{
    if (item.StartsWith("food_"))
    {
        int temp = int.Parse(item.Skip(5).Take(8).ToString());

        if (temp>number){number=temp; currentFile = item;}
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you . one more thing .. how can I keep the exe file to other location so that other users can see the exe only and check by clicking on the exe o nly

Comment: I want to keep the exe file outside the bin folder to some other location .. How can it be possible.

Comment: @DebopamChatterjee may want to have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx

Comment: hello if the food_020114.txt and food_010114.txt are there in the same location and i want to retrive the row count for the current file only then how could I do this ?

Comment: @DebopamChatterjee what do you mean with `current file`?

Comment: current file means food_020114.txt

Comment: you can get the list of file names in a folder, match them to a pattern like `food_xxxxxx.txt` and find out which one is greater.

Comment: To get files in a folder: `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: can you please share te code for me bro .. @hossein narimani rad